# Enable WiFi not showing up on a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, wireless

I recently switched from Elementary OS to Ubuntu 15.10 for Virtualbox,
but when I completed the installation and tried to connect to my local WiFi network, there was no Enable WiFi button. Only an Enable Networks button.

The Network Connections window also only shows a wired Ethernet Connection, which I've never even used on this laptop.

EDIT:

When I use ifconfig -a it only shows the

> enp5s0

And

> lo

No wlan0.

Can someone please help?

The output of

> lspci | grep -i intel

Is

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) Thermal Subsystem (rev 03)
```

lspci | grep -i wireless    gives no output

Comment: Give us output of: `lspci | grep -i intel` and `lspci | grep -i wireless`

Comment: You can not manage wifi from a guest network. You use the host system. It is shown as a wired network.

Comment: added the outputs

Comment: This output shows virtual devices.

Comment: Here is official troubleshooting guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html

Comment: I installed Ubuntu using a USB device, I don't know what the difference is with aVirtual Machine ?

Comment: Are you run it on bare metal or in VirtualBox? There is no Wi-Fi in VirtualBox.

Comment: No, I'm not running it in VirtualBox

Answer (score 2):

You cannot connect wireless networks from a guest system in VirtualBox.

You need to connect from the host system.

In this case the guest system, will have network access.